# How to add multiply watermarks in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I try to find a way to add a lot of watermarks in same sheet in Excel. 
Under meaning of watermark I mean a picture behind the grid. Excel allows to add only one picture per sheet (behind the grid), but I need many of them. I tried to use background pasting and running titles in the sheet. Also, I tried to use activeX (vba) elements with "behind the grid" but this way as far I can judge doesn't fulfill my needs.

Please, if it is possible, help me! :)

For instance I have two pictures and I need to place them behind the grid. In order to fill cells with values "on pictures" like watermarks

Example:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/m8FQxUyVOAYbJpWu1

Comment: You could merge all the pictures into one picture and add that one big picture ad background image.

Comment: Is the objective just background wallpaper to see while you work in Excel, or an image that is part of the worksheet and will print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I don't have perfect idea how multiple watermarks can be added to the Sheet using proper Excel commands, but the following solution works for me.*

**Check the Screen Shot:**

[image]

- Either create or insert few ready made figures in Paint.
- Place the background text in this figure at the desired locations.
  For this you can use Word Art and Print Screen to get watermark-like
  fonts.
- Set the figure as a background picture for the worksheet.
- Use Page-layout, Page setup, Background commands.

**Note,** *Apply write proportion to get the right spacing between the text, the problem you can face is, the background does not zoom at all.*

Comment: Could you  please make some screenshots, dont understand what do you mean

Comment: @Andre, using screen shot it's difficult to demonstrate the entire process. What I tried to say, make one image in Paint Brush it's size should be little bigger add some TEXT using Word ART and finally use Page Layout command to set the Paint Brush picture as background. Only this much you need to do !!

Comment: I added an example in my first message!

Comment: @Andre, check the answer I've uploaded the Screen Shot, where you find 3 different watermark image in the  background of the sheet.

Comment: I am not nature english speaker so I tried to explain what I am doing to follow your instructions.Firtly I created 3 pictures in paint. Then I copy and paste them in worksheet (just Cntrl +C and Cntrl + V). It looks like:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/qANyRyvg1mjO52BW2
Then I dont understand what I should to do to hide them behind the grip. Sorry for annoying, but really need you help!

Comment: if I understood it correctly. You created one merge picture in Paint and then pasted it like header

Comment: @Andre, yes u r write, it is the best possibility to add multiple watermark images to worksheet, as background picture.